# Error while migrating tables into db...table already exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

[image]

When i migrate my tables into db, it gives this error

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not
>   null auto_increment primary key, `body` longtext not null, `url`
>   varchar(255) null, `user_id`   int unsigned not null, `commentable_id`
>   int unsigned not null, `commentable_type` varchar(191) not null,
>   `created_a   t` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default
>   character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci) In Connection.php line 449:
>    SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'users' already exists

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if(!Schema::hasTable('users')){
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table-> string('name');
                $table-> string('email')->unique();
                $table-> string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table -> string('first_name') -> nullabel();
            $table -> string('middle_name') -> nullabel();
            $table -> string('last_name') -> nullabel();
            $table -> string('city') -> nullabel();
            $table -> integer('role') -> unsigned();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
```

I dropped all the tables from database then i tried but same error given

Comment: try this code: `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Comment: i did but didn't work for me

Comment: Please post your migrations, are you defining the user table twice?

Comment: Check your `.env` file and see if the database name is what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try either splitting into two migrations or adding all fields at once:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table-> string('name');
                $table-> string('email')->unique();
                $table-> string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
                $table -> string('first_name') -> nullable();
                $table -> string('middle_name') -> nullable();
                $table -> string('last_name') -> nullable();
                $table -> string('city') -> nullable();
                $table -> integer('role') -> unsigned();
            });
```

Please note: you have also spelt nullable wrong.

Comment: It works i used `user` in create table of table comments instead of comments=, now its working thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using Laravel 5.5 so you must have make **"php artisan migrate"** without edit your **AppServiceProvider.php** file inside the boot method.

So I recomend you to delete your tables from the database with **"php artisan tinker"** Then **"Schema::drop('users')(and exit with q)"**.

After that you have to edit your **"AppServiceProvider.php"** file, so use this link to help you: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

When when you have already edited the file you can now make the **"php artisan migrate:rollback"** and after that **"php artisan migrate"**

that works with me !